# How do you stop a loop when a condition is met?

Tags: python, loops

I'm a complete newbie to the coding trying my hands on python. While coding a simple program to calculate the age I ran into an error I cannot seem to fix no matter how hard I try. The code is pasted below. The program runs as far as I enter an year in the future, however when an year which has passed is used, the code loops again asking if the year is correct. Any help is appreciated.

```
from datetime import date

current_year = (date.today().year)
print('What is your age?') 
myAge = input()
print('future_year?')
your_age_in_a_future_year= input()
future_age= int(myAge)+ (int(your_age_in_a_future_year)) - int(current_year)

def process ():
    if future_age > 0:
        print(future_age)
    else:
        print('do you really want to go back in time?, enter "yes" or "no"')
    answer = input()
    if answer =='yes':
        print (future_age)
    if answer == 'no':
        print ('cya')
    while answer != 'yes' or 'no':
        print ('enter correct response')
        process ()
        
process()
```

Comment: Did you take several days to read [the documentation of Python](https://docs.python.org/) ???

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you write this code yourself? Or do you want us to explain code from others? Either way, this question is not on-topic here. You might want to break down the code into smaller pieces, temporarily print variables, etc. to understand what's happening. The question "how do you stop a loop?" can be found in the documentation and is likely already answered here too. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, your function just needs to contain a `while` loop with an appropriate condition, and then there is no need to break out from it, or do a recursive call or anything.

```
def process():
    if future_age > 0:
        print(future_age)
    else:
        print('do you really want to go back in time?, enter "yes" or "no"')
        answer = None
        while answer not in ('yes', 'no'):
            answer = input()
            if answer == 'yes':
                print(future_age)
            elif answer == 'no':
                print('cya')
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
...
   if future_age > 0:

        print(future_age)
        return

    else:

        print('do you really want to go back in time?, enter "yes" or "no"')
...
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back, you may have been thrown off by my poor question formation but, the other answer seem to have solved the issue.